# How to count estimated time and show in table using angular js?

Tags: angularjs

i have one list for show data in table and i am work in angularjs. and i am getting success for show data. and in my data one filed have nama **follower count**. so on page load table is show and in the background my one process is running for the get followers form the instagram api.so in the process i have settimeout for 1 - 1 followers take and take 5 sec wit and then after go 2nd followers take. that type one by one followers take in to 5 sec interval after.so i am show followers count in the table so here i need show also estimated time in which time period your followers is download.

for ex=> i have 16 followers and in the background 1 followers take and after wit for the 5 sec so my 16 followers in which time period after download. for ex. 1min, 1hours,1 day, etc...

Here is my table html =>

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Target UserName</th>
      <th>Followers</th>
      <th>Status</th>
     <th>Estimated time</th>        
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="r in Result">
        <td>{{r.target_username}}</td>
        <td>{{r.followres_count}}</td>
        <td>{{r.Flage ? "Done" : "running"}}</td>
        <td>{{r.followres_count * 5 }}</td> // here i have try like this but not get propare answer.        
    </tr>
</table>
```

here my data look like =>

```
TARGET      FOLLOWERS   STATUS  ESTIMATED TIME  
 abc           16       Done             80
 t            3000       Done           15000
```

Comment: Are you getting total count  in this `r.followres_count`?

Comment: @Durga yes i am total followres count getting in r.followres_count

Comment: you want to show `80` as `1min 20sec` ?

Comment: yes i want show time in depend on followres count in which period between download like 1min 20sec, 1 hours1 1 days,etc..

Comment: @Durga my 80 is wrong idk there what time is come

Comment: @Durga any idea how can do that this issue and fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.setValue = function(){
     var x = 11111150000;
     var time = moment.duration(x);
     var day = time.days();
     var hr = time.hours();
     var min = time.minutes();
     var sec = time.seconds();
     var y = (day ? day +' days ' : '') + (hr ? hr +' hours ' : '') + (min ? min +' min ':'' ) + ( sec ? sec +' sec':'');
     return y;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td ng-bind="setValue()"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Use [moment.duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) to get the time in time format, if you know specific time.

Comment: my followers total count is 16 then in background 1 by 1 followers download between 5 sec interval so in which time period this 16 followers download done? so with your solution how can pass my count and multiply with 5 sec ?

Comment: @Edit pass followers total to function and in your case `x = folowersTotal*5*1000;`

Comment: my table in ng-repeat so how can i call this funcation for every raw?

Comment: @Edit `<td ng-bind='functionName(r.followres_count)'></td>`